# Do we need to start Kafka for each user if started as root

Tags: hadoop, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Hello I am new to `kafka` and `zookeeper` concept. I have installed `kafka` and `zookeeper` in root and started as root user as **nohup**. The `jps` command gives output as:

> root@rachita-Aspire-V7-481P:/usr/share/zookeeper/bin# jps
>
> 4037 Elasticsearch
>
> 1689 QuorumPeerMain
>
> 9899 Kafka
>
> 1692 Jps
>
> 3469 QuorumPeerMain

But when I try `jps` for `rachita` user the output is:

> rachita@rachita-Aspire-V7-481P:/usr/share/zookeeper/bin$ jps
>
> 3261 Jps

Do I need to start `kafka` for every user on my machine who wish to use it?

Please give me any suggestions.

Also `Haddop` is installed as a separate user called `hduser` inside a group called `hadoop`. So can any user start all `hadoop` daemons or only `hduser` can do it.

Please help me with this. I am getting confused.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. No, we don't need to start it for each user. Service should be started once by kafka-server-start on each node, which configured for kafka broker. If you are running kafka-server-start several times on a single node, you will start multiple brokers in it. Your user just does not have permissions to maintain the service, that is why you don't see it.
2. Best practice is to create a separate user as a member of hadoop group for each hadoop deamon and start it under this user account.

Comment: So If  iunderstood correct, should I install kafka and zookeeper inside a separate user like "hduser" within hadoop group and then run kafka and zookeeper within it? So doing that will start hadoop, kafka and zookeeper within hadoop group. Is that correct?

Comment: You should have three users - hduser, kafka and zookeeper. They should be the members of hadoop group. And it is on you to configurate your hadoop to start these daemons under separate user accounts. Just pushing them into hadoop group will not make them start automatically in the way I described.

Comment: Thanks Alex, I got your point. Thank you for your suggestions.